# GRUB2 issue after removing windows and reinstalling ubuntu

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

**Short version**
Cannot restore EFI partition with boot repair. Create a proper partition **AND** put a /EFI/ folder into it, then used boot repair

**Original question**

I originally had a dual boot with win 8 on it. Deleting it also bricked my EFI boot partition. I eventually reinstalled Ubuntu 14.04 via a live USB as my kernel images were ruined by boot-repair, hoping this would also fix the boot, but that didn't work.

My current partition status:

[image]

where sda3 is the former windows partition, and sda6 contains data (backed up). sda2 holds my ubuntu install.

**edit**
I removed sda1 and placed the bios_grub flagged partition at the start of the disk, reinstalled grub and updated, but to no avail
**/edit**

My current boot status is given here:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/11774252/

Despite this, if I boot without my live usb in, I only get a black (non grub) screen stating that all boot option have been tried.

I can manually boot the sda2 ubuntu by running grub from the usb key in UEFI mode, pressing c to get the CLI interface, and using

```
grub> linux (hd1,gpt2)/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
grub> initrd (hd1,gpt2)/initrd.img
grub> boot
```

Then, I tried both using boot-repair and installing grub manually by

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

both end up fine with no errors, but I still get the black screen.

Also, I am unable to boot the system manually if a run my grub on the usb key in non UEFI mode, since I cannot reach the Command Line Interface in this case (holding shift leads to a crappy grub GUI and I am stuck there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it , it was pretty silly.

I used `boot-repair` to restore the EFI partition.

I created a FAT32 partition of 230mb at the head of the disk and flagged it as boot using `gparted`. After this, the `boot-repair` was still complaining about missing the EFI partition ("Your system boot is in efi mode but no efi partition was found. You might want to try again after creating a efi partition(fat32,~100-200mb,head of disk, boot flag)"

Apparently, it is not enough to have the partition as required by the error message. So just did this:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda4 /media
sudo mkdir /media/EFI
```

then boot repair correctly found `sda4` to be the partition to installe the EFI grub and all worked fine.

I don't know if it is relevant, but I also installed the package `grub-efi-amd64-signed` at some point.

Comment: I've heard another recent tale of Boot Repair failing to detect an ESP. Maybe they've developed a bug. (I didn't save the URL for the other report, and I'm not sure where it was.)

Comment: Hi Rod, was it maybe my previous question? (Posted two days ago and now deleted it and posted this one instead)